# Whats wrong with this php code that goes directly in without having log in first?

Tags: php, class, session, authentication, verification

I have a form that only opens if you're logged in, or at least thats what I'm trying to do, but it opens without having to do it.  When I go to the log in page it sends me to the other page like if I was logging in, but it doesn't even show me the login page, heres the code:

this one is for the log in:

```
<?php
  include ("conexion/conexion.php");
  include("usuarios.class.php");

$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$clave= $_POST['clave'];

$objUsuario = new usuarios;
    $srt= $objUsuario->autenticar_usuario($usuario,$clave,1);
    $num =mysql_num_rows($srt);

if($usuario=="" || $clave==""){
 $mensaje="campos en blanco";
 header("location:loginusuario.php?mensaje=$mensaje");  
}else 
{
    $objUsuario = new usuarios;
    $srt= $objUsuario->autenticar_usuario($usuario,$clave,1);
    $num =mysql_num_rows($srt);
    }
if($num <= 0){
        $mensaje="Usuario y/o clave Incorrectos";
         header("location:loginusuario.php?mensaje=$mensaje");  
    }else{

        $row=mysql_fetch_array($srt);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['log'] = 's'; 
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
         header("location:contrataciones.php"); 

    }

?>
```

this is for the security file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['log']!= 's'){ 
        $mensaje="Iniciar sesion";
 header("location:loginusuario.php?mensaje=$mensaje");  

        }

?>
```

and this is the class I'm using

```
<?php 
  class usuarios
  {

    function usuarios() {

    } 
    function autenticar_usuario($usuario,$clave){
        $sel="select usuario,clave from usuarios where usuario='".$usuario."' and clave='".$clave."' ";
        $srt=mysql_query($sel) or die($sel);
        return $srt;

    }
?>
```

please tell me what am I doing wrong I'm a noob in this so I dont really get whats the problem

Comment: You need to exit()  after you write the redirect header.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart all of them?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it writes the header and keeps executing.

Comment: Better yet, wrap up the header() and exit() in a redirect () function.

Comment: @user3117314 - you need to add some basic debugging in here. If it's letting you past the password check, figure out how. There are `if` statements checking if you're logged in - echo out the values that you're checking, and make sure that they're correct. Check your database queries, and make sure they're checking the right information. Also - you're calling `autenticar_usuario` twice, and once is before you've check that you have a username and password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats wrong with this php code to create a $\_session to deny access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671262/whats-wrong-with-this-php-code-to-create-a-session-to-deny-access). Not really sure what's a duplicate of what, all your 4 questions by seem to be more or less the same...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I used the exit but now it is acting like I havent fill the fields and says theres a loop

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    //statement

    //statement
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_SESSION['session_var_name'])){
    //statement

    //statement
}
```